# How can I change the line spacing for one paragraph in an HTML email template?

Tags: html

I would like to add html commands just before and just after a set of lines, that would reduce the spacing between the lines.  Commands I've found on Internet sites don't work, or they need to be within other commands.

Commands I've found on Internet sites don't work, or they need to be within other commands.  I tried commands such as line-height=50%.

**Here is the result**

Business Analyst:

User Testing Resources:

Here is the code:

```
<html><head>
  <meta name="generator" content=  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  <title>$BEGINSUBJECT()$NOTIFICATION() - $ITEMNUMBER()$FIELDVALUE(ID) $TTID()$ENDSUBJECT()</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:12px;}
  a.attachlink:link { color: #0000FF }
  a.attachlink:visited { color: #0000FF }
  a.attachlink:hover { color: #006600 } 
  .itemTitle{ font-size:120%; padding: 0px;  color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom:thin solid Navy; background-color: Navy;  }
  .itemColor{ color: #FFFFFF;}
  td {padding:4px; vertical-align:top;} 
  td.sidebar{     color: #333;}
  .fieldNames {color: #333; white-space:nowrap; font-weight: bold;}
  .footer{ color: #818181; font-size:80%; font-style: italic; }
  .greyborder{background-color:#f7f7f7; border:thin #999 solid; width:auto;}
  </style></head>
<body>   <table>    <tbody><tr>      <td>        <table class="itemTitle">          <tbody><tr>            <td class="itemColor"> 
<b>$ITEMNUMBER()$FIELDVALUE(ID)</b> ($FIELDVALUE(TITLE)) <b>Requires Action</b> </td>          </tr>        </tbody></table>      </td>    </tr>    <tr>        <td>    <b> <table width="100%"> 
Please transition <b>$ITEMNUMBER()$FIELDVALUE(ID)</b> in state <b>$FIELDVALUE(STATE).</b><br> <br>      
To open $ITEMNUMBER()$FIELDVALUE(ID) $LINK(TRUE, click here.)       <font color="#ff0000">
Your prompt attention to this request is greatly appreciated.</font></td></tr>            <tr><td>   $IF(CANVIEW)<b>
$FIELDS(1) <tr> <td>
<font color="#FF0000">This is a SYSTEM GENERATED EMAIL. Please do not reply.<br></font></tr></td><tr><td>
Thank you!    <br>    </td>    </tr>    </tbody></table>    <hr color="navy"> <br> <font color="#d0d0d0" size="1">
Reference: $NOTIFICATION()</font></body></html>
```

Comment: A working example would be useful here with a closing table tag and the css you're currently using.

Answer (score 1):

You want `line-height`. Being that it is an email template this `style` attribute needs to be applied on each element you need it on. The value is relative to the font-size, where 1 is equal to 100%, so if the font size is `16px` and line-height is set to `1.5`, that would be the same as saying `line-height: 24px;`. Hope that makes sense!

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="line-height: 1.6;">
    <b>Some looser text in this row</b><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dignissim, dolor ac iaculis euismod, diam felis elementum nibh, et interdum augue odio eu est. Nam tempor sapien eu arcu tristique rhoncus. Cras magna orci, finibus eget est nec, pharetra elementum lectus. 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="line-height: 1.1;">
    <b>Some tighter text in this row</b><br/>
    In luctus, ex sit amet tincidunt maximus, neque sapien consequat lorem, quis sagittis sem neque eget massa. Donec tincidunt facilisis lacus sit amet mattis. Aliquam convallis, risus in tristique lacinia, nibh purus mollis justo, ut vestibulum dui mauris et libero. Nam purus quam, vestibulum sed velit nec, tempor posuere lacus. Fusce dignissim ac urna eget euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A paragraph should be created using `<p> </p>`, and not using a table workaround.
2. you style each paragraph using `class="someClass"` (a css file).
3. if you want to indent something - wrap it with `<div></div>` and style it accordingly. Don't use `&nbsp;`. use `style = "margin : 20px"` or something like that.

Html is a hypertext language. If you are new to it I can recommend http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: Sorry--I have replaced the lines I had originally wanted to tighten up, with a tag - $FIELDS() - but I still wish to narrow the line-spacing between the lines beginning "Please transition" and "To open"; also between the lines at the bottom, beginning "This is a" and "Thank you".